# How to Extract Value Keys From JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, key

I have following JSON format and I want to extract keys from it.

I want to get following keys

**covg_AccdntDeath_Slf ,
covg_DILong_Slf ,
covg_LITwentyYr_Slf ,
covg_LITenYr_Slf ,
covg_GrpOffOvr_Slf ,
covg_LIAnnual_Slf ,
txtCampaignCode ,
associationAccronym**

And this is my JSON data:

```
{  
  "covg_AccdntDeath_Slf":{  
    "txtGNumber":"G-29003-0",
    "txtPlanName":"Accidental Death and Dismemberment Insurance",
    "hidProdCode":"999",
    "rdTypeOfCovg":"New",
    "slidBenefitAmt":"50000",
    "productCategory":"AD"
  },
  "covg_DILong_Slf":{  
    "txtGNumber":"G-29002-0",
    "txtPlanName":"Long Term Disability",
    "hidProdCode":"601-a",
    "rdTypeOfCovg":"New",
    "txtMaxBenefitAmt":"$15,000",
    "selWaitingPeriod":"30 Days",
    "slidMonBenefitAmt":"1000",
    "productCategory":"DI"
  },
  "covg_LITwentyYr_Slf":{  
    "txtGNumber":"G-29005-0",
    "txtPlanName":"20-Year Level Term Life Insurance",
    "hidProdCode":"121",
    "rdTypeOfCovg":"New",
    "slidBenefitAmt":"100000",
    "productCategory":"LI"
  },
  "covg_LITenYr_Slf":{  
    "txtGNumber":"G-29004-0",
    "txtPlanName":"10-Year Level Term Life Insurance",
    "hidProdCode":"102",
    "rdTypeOfCovg":"New",
    "slidBenefitAmt":"100000",
    "productCategory":"LI"
  },
  "covg_GrpOffOvr_Slf":{  
    "txtGNumber":"G-29002-1",
    "txtPlanName":"Office Overhead Expense Disability Insurance",
    "hidProdCode":"603",
    "rdTypeOfCovg":"New",
    "slidBenefitAmt":"1000",
    "txtMaxBenefitAmt":"$20,000",
    "selWaitingPeriod":"30 Days",
    "selBenefitDuration":"24 months",
    "productCategory":"OO"
  },
  "covg_LIAnnual_Slf":{  
    "txtGNumber":"G-29000-0",
    "txtPlanName":"Traditional Term Life Insurance",
    "hidProdCode":"99999",
    "rdTypeOfCovg":"New",
    "slidBenefitAmt":"100000",
    "productCategory":"LI"
  },
  "txtCampaignCode":"",
  "associationAccronym":"ACS"
}
```

I have tried following code.

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var input = above JSON String.
        var keys = [];
        console.log('Length : '+input.length);
        for(var i = 0;i<input.length;i++)
        {
            Object.keys(input[i]).forEach(function(key){
                if(keys.indexOf(key) == -1)
                {
                    keys.push(key);
                }
            });
        }
        console.log('KKKK: '+keys);
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try objectName[keyName]????

Comment: `JSON.parse(json)` then `Object.keys(obj)` will give you an array of keys. Just remove the ones you don't want.

Comment: [Create an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) from the JSON, then use a suitable [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). For more complex object constructions, please see [Access nested objects, arrays or json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all that code.

1) Parse your JSON to an object: `var obj = JSON.parse(json);`.

2) Object don't have a length so that makes the loop redundant. `Object.keys(obj)` does have a length tho.

3) You're iterating over the object keys and placing them in a new array. `Object.keys(obj)` returns an array anyway and because keys can't be duplicates in an object the condition that checks whether the current key is in `keys` is also redundant.

All you need is `Object.keys(obj)` and then you can use `forEach` to iterate over the array.

Something like:

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
keys.forEach(function (el) { console.log(el); });
```

Or even just:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (el) { console.log(el); });
```